# How to compare the directory names using Perl

Tags: perl

I just want match the Main directory and sub directory name, whether both names are equal or not and sub directory and main directory name should be matched with file name. Can anyone help on my request please using Perl script.

For Example:

```
Main-Directory :XXX
Sub Directory :XXX
File name: XXX
```

Ans should be "All the names are equal"

This is what I've tried:

```
#!perl
use Cwd qw(abs_path);

opendir (DIR,'.');
my @folder = readdir(DIR);
foreach my $f (@folder)
{
    next if ($f =~ /\./);
    print "$f\n";

    my $path = abs_path($0);
    opendir (DIR,'$path');
    my @subfolder = readdir(DIR);

    foreach my $sf (@subfolder)
    {
        next if ($sf =~ /\./);
        print "$sf\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What output does it produce?

Comment: I quite like `File::Find` as a module to use to solve this sort of problem. It's probably worth having a look at it's documentation.

Comment: Can you try re-wording your question? It's not totally clear what you're trying to do. Perhaps provide an example file structure and the output you would expect.

Comment: Main Folder name: f1-02-00018
   Sub folders name: epub -> fl-02-00018.epub;
       html -> f1-02-00018-HTML.zip;
              pdf  -> f1-02-00018.pdf;
       xml  -> f1-02-00018.zip;

I just want to match whether folder name and file names are equal or not[without file extension].

   Can anyone please help on this using perl script.

Comment: While installing the PPM i am getting the error like as below.

Please help on this to resolve this issue.

Synchronizing Database ... done
----------


Bit-Vector marked for install
Installing package ... 
  Downloading Bit-Vector-7.2 ... redirect
  Downloading Bit-Vector-7.2 ... failed 401 Authorization Required
Installing package failed


----------


ERROR: 401 Authorization Required

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use File::Find;

sub wanted {
    return unless (-f $_);
    my @path_element=split('/', $File::Find::name);
    print if ($path_element[-1] eq $path_element[-2] && $path_element[-1] eq $path_element[-3]);
}

find(\&wanted,".");
```

**how it works**

find runs the sub "wanted" on each file in the tree.
if the file is a type "f" ( ie a normal non directory file )then it checks if the file, it's directory and the directory the directory is in have the same name.  If this is the case then it prints the file name

this does not give exactly the output you requested but it is trivial to alter it to do so

you may need to alter the "split" to use a different path seperator on non unix systems

hope this helps